# BS .nav-pills stay depressed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if it is related to the `focus` element state but when I click on one of the `.nav-pills` (see example below) it appears to become `.active`, even when I move my mouse off it, until I click elsewhere on the page. On the Google Chrome web inspector it shows no evidence of this. I want the first pill to be the only active pill on my page.

```css
/* Primary Syle Sheet */

/* Basic Typography */

#topnav {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#topnav .nav-pills > li {
 margin-left: 11px;
 margin-right: 11px;
 text-size: 100px;
}

#topnav>.nav-pills>li>a {
 padding-top: 11px;
 padding-bottom: 11px;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #333;
}

#topnav>.nav-pills>li.active>a, #topnav>.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #navbar-nav>li>a {
     padding-top: 15px;
     padding-bottom: 15px;
     margin-top: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    #navbar-nav {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center !important;
   }
   #navbar-nav > li {
       float: none;
       display: inline-block;
    }
}

.center-pills {
 display: inline-block;
}

.h1 small.sbttl, .h2 small.sbttl, .h3 small.sbttl, .h4 small.sbttl, .h5 small.sbttl, .h6 small.sbttl, h1 small.sbttl, h2 small.sbttl, h3 small.sbttl, h4 small.sbttl, h5 small.sbttl, h6 small.sbttl {
 display: block;
 font-size: 33%;
 color: inherit !important;
 opacity: 0.75;
}

/* Targeted Stylings */

header {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 header .brand-name {
     padding-top: 200px !important;
     padding-bottom: 200px !important;
 }
}

header .brand-name {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

header .brand-name h1 {
 font-size: 75px;
 font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Example</title>
    
    <!-- Primary Stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/styles_1.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" class="index">
   <header>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="brand-name">
      <h1>Title <small class="sbttl">Subtitle</small></h1>
     </div>
    
     <!-- Initial -->
     <div class="container text-center" id="topnav">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">content</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">content</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">content</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Sorry if I've included too much in my snippet, I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `active` modifier will always make the designated button appear active. In your example you have done it correctly, you are just seeing the `hover` modifier. You can change it with

```
li:hover{
   /*insert code here
}
```

in css.

Comment: So... to stop it from staying in that state until I click somewhere else on the page I need to?

Comment: You want to remove everything from the `li:hover` in your CSS, or assign it something constant like `li:hover { color:black; }` or whatever works best for your design.

Comment: but then I would not be able to see the hover state when the mouse actually hovers over it. Plus, when it happens the color of the pill does not match the color of a pill with `:hover`, so I'm not sure this solution is correct

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Primary Syle Sheet */

/* Basic Typography */

#topnav {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#topnav .nav-pills > li {
 margin-left: 11px;
 margin-right: 11px;
 text-size: 100px;
}

#topnav>.nav-pills>li>a {
 padding-top: 11px;
 padding-bottom: 11px;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #333;
}

#topnav>.nav-pills>li.active>a, #topnav>.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.nav-pills>li>a:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
}

#navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #navbar-nav>li>a {
     padding-top: 15px;
     padding-bottom: 15px;
     margin-top: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    #navbar-nav {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center !important;
   }
   #navbar-nav > li {
       float: none;
       display: inline-block;
    }
}

.center-pills {
 display: inline-block;
}

.h1 small.sbttl, .h2 small.sbttl, .h3 small.sbttl, .h4 small.sbttl, .h5 small.sbttl, .h6 small.sbttl, h1 small.sbttl, h2 small.sbttl, h3 small.sbttl, h4 small.sbttl, h5 small.sbttl, h6 small.sbttl {
 display: block;
 font-size: 33%;
 color: inherit !important;
 opacity: 0.75;
}

/* Targeted Stylings */

header {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 header .brand-name {
     padding-top: 200px !important;
     padding-bottom: 200px !important;
 }
}

header .brand-name {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

header .brand-name h1 {
 font-size: 75px;
 font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Example</title>
    
   

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Primary Stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/styles_1.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" class="index">
   <header>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="brand-name">
      <h1>Title <small class="sbttl">Subtitle</small></h1>
     </div>
    
     <!-- Initial -->
     <div class="container text-center" id="topnav">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
       <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="pill">content</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#">content</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#">content</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#">content</a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>

   
  </body>
</html>
```

> hi, you have to use data-toggle="pill" with your anchor tags... happy
>   coding

Comment: Thanks for your help but your solution is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
.li:active {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```

use this css so that when your link is click its background color change to yellow which won't affects your overall layout :)

Comment: This isn't working either. I would like to know why `#topnav .li:not(.active)>a:not(:hover) {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}`